# Is it possible to create Tessellation table in schema other than sysspatial

Tags: geoserver

As per geoserver teradata documentation, tessellation table is required in sys spatial schema only.

My question is - Is it possible to configure geoserver to pick the tessellation table from a different schema? Has anyone tried it with success?

I tried changing the tessellation table schema name while creating the datastore, but still geoserver looks for this table in syssptial schema only.

Any inputs?